# How to correctly embed php code in a Wordpress page template?

Tags: php, wordpress, constructor

I am using Wordpress with the Constructor theme. I came accross the following totorial on building an easy crud application:
http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/app/crud3.php

I have customized it to my needs, a correctly working demo can be found here:
http://www.szerelmifajdalomklinika.hu/wp-content/themes/constructor/index2.html#

The code for index2.html is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">

<style type="text/css">
    form{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .dv-table td{
        border:0;
    }
    .dv-table input{
        border:1px solid #ccc;
    }
</style>





<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/datagrid-detailview.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#dgpartner').datagrid({
            view: detailview,
            detailFormatter:function(index,row){
                return '<div class="ddv"></div>';
            },
            onExpandRow: function(index,row){
                var ddv = $(this).datagrid('getRowDetail',index).find('div.ddv');
                ddv.panel({
                    border:false,
                    cache:true,
                    href:'show_form.php?index='+index,
                    onLoad:function(){
                        $('#dgpartner').datagrid('fixDetailRowHeight',index);
                        $('#dgpartner').datagrid('selectRow',index);
                        $('#dgpartner').datagrid('getRowDetail',index).find('form').form('load',row);
                    }
                });
                $('#dgpartner').datagrid('fixDetailRowHeight',index);
            }
        });
    });
    function saveItem(index){
        var row = $('#dgpartner').datagrid('getRows')[index];
        var url = row.isNewRecord ? 'save_user.php' : 'update_user.php?partner_id='+row.partner_id;
        $('#dgpartner').datagrid('getRowDetail',index).find('form').form('submit',{
            url: url,
            onSubmit: function(){
                return $(this).form('validate');
            },
            success: function(data){
                data = eval('('+data+')');
                data.isNewRecord = false;
                $('#dgpartner').datagrid('collapseRow',index);
                $('#dgpartner').datagrid('updateRow',{
                    index: index,
                    row: data
                });
            }
        });
    }
    function cancelItem(index){
        var row = $('#dgpartner').datagrid('getRows')[index];
        if (row.isNewRecord){
            $('#dgpartner').datagrid('deleteRow',index);
        } else {
            $('#dgpartner').datagrid('collapseRow',index);
        }
    }
    function destroyItem(){
        var row = $('#dgpartner').datagrid('getSelected');
        if (row){
            $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to remove this user?',function(r){
                if (r){
                    var index = $('#dgpartner').datagrid('getRowIndex',row);
                    $.post('destroy_user.php',{partner_id:row.partner_id},function(){
                        $('#dgpartner').datagrid('deleteRow',index);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
    function newItem(){
        $('#dgpartner').datagrid('appendRow',{isNewRecord:true});
        var index = $('#dgpartner').datagrid('getRows').length - 1;
        $('#dgpartner').datagrid('expandRow', index);
        $('#dgpartner').datagrid('selectRow', index);
    }
</script>



<table id="dgpartner" title="Partnerek" style="width:900px;height:250px"
        url="get_users.php"
        toolbar="#toolbar" pagination="true"
        fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th field="partner_nickname" width="50">Partner beceneve</th>
            <th field="partner_description" width="50">Partner leírása</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<div id="toolbar">
    <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-add" plain="true" onclick="newItem()">New</a>
    <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-remove" plain="true" onclick="destroyItem()">Destroy</a>
</div>
```

I would like to make this to a page template. It can be found here http://www.szerelmifajdalomklinika.hu/kapcsolati-vazlat/

The code for the template file template-szerelmi-partner_raw.php is the following (abowe pasted to the container):

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Kapcsolat-oldal
*/
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Constructor
 * 
 */


get_header(); ?>
<div id="content" class="box shadow opacity <?php the_constructor_layout_class() ?>">
    <div id="container" >

    <?php $post = get_page(get_query_var('page_id')); $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); echo $content;  ?>


        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">

 <style type="text/css">
        form{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        .dv-table td{
            border:0;
        }
        .dv-table input{
            border:1px solid #ccc;
        }
    </style>





    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/datagrid-detailview.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#dgpartner').datagrid({
                view: detailview,
                detailFormatter:function(index,row){
                    return '<div class="ddv"></div>';
                },
                onExpandRow: function(index,row){
                    var ddv = $(this).datagrid('getRowDetail',index).find('div.ddv');
                    ddv.panel({
                        border:false,
                        cache:true,
                        href:'show_form.php?index='+index,
                        onLoad:function(){
                            $('#dgpartner').datagrid('fixDetailRowHeight',index);
                            $('#dgpartner').datagrid('selectRow',index);
                            $('#dgpartner').datagrid('getRowDetail',index).find('form').form('load',row);
                        }
                    });
                    $('#dgpartner').datagrid('fixDetailRowHeight',index);
                }
            });
        });
        function saveItem(index){
            var row = $('#dgpartner').datagrid('getRows')[index];
            var url = row.isNewRecord ? 'save_user.php' : 'update_user.php?partner_id='+row.partner_id;
            $('#dgpartner').datagrid('getRowDetail',index).find('form').form('submit',{
                url: url,
                onSubmit: function(){
                    return $(this).form('validate');
                },
                success: function(data){
                    data = eval('('+data+')');
                    data.isNewRecord = false;
                    $('#dgpartner').datagrid('collapseRow',index);
                    $('#dgpartner').datagrid('updateRow',{
                        index: index,
                        row: data
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        function cancelItem(index){
            var row = $('#dgpartner').datagrid('getRows')[index];
            if (row.isNewRecord){
                $('#dgpartner').datagrid('deleteRow',index);
            } else {
                $('#dgpartner').datagrid('collapseRow',index);
            }
        }
        function destroyItem(){
            var row = $('#dgpartner').datagrid('getSelected');
            if (row){
                $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to remove this user?',function(r){
                    if (r){
                        var index = $('#dgpartner').datagrid('getRowIndex',row);
                        $.post('destroy_user.php',{partner_id:row.partner_id},function(){
                            $('#dgpartner').datagrid('deleteRow',index);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        function newItem(){
            $('#dgpartner').datagrid('appendRow',{isNewRecord:true});
            var index = $('#dgpartner').datagrid('getRows').length - 1;
            $('#dgpartner').datagrid('expandRow', index);
            $('#dgpartner').datagrid('selectRow', index);
        }
    </script>



    <table id="dgpartner" title="Partnerek" style="width:900px;height:250px"
            url="get_users.php"
            toolbar="#toolbar" pagination="true"
            fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th field="partner_nickname" width="50">Partner beceneve</th>
                <th field="partner_description" width="50">Partner leírása</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <div id="toolbar">
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-add" plain="true" onclick="newItem()">New</a>
        <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-remove" plain="true" onclick="destroyItem()">Destroy</a>
    </div>

    </div><!-- id='container' -->
    <?php get_constructor_sidebar(); ?>
</div><!-- id='content' -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

As you can see, the second variant does not work correctly. Even the table header is rendered badly. **How can I correcly import this code to a page template?**

Some thoughts on what might be the problem:
In the called files, (example get_users.php), there is a `include 'conn.php';` with `$conn = @mysql_connect(xxx);` maybe, this needs to be interchanged with the wordpress default connection? If so, how?

Mentioned files have include, and there are some stuff outside of the theme's header.php . If I copy all there, it does not solve the issue.

Thank you for the help.

Sziro

Comment: "As you can see, the second variant does not work correctly." Actually, we can't see. What is not working in the second version that you need to work?

Comment: I have included links for the first and second variant: http://www.szerelmifajdalomklinika.hu/wp-content/themes/constructor/index2.html# and http://www.szerelmifajdalomklinika.hu/kapcsolati-vazlat/ . What needs to work is the listing, adding new element, modifiing, deleting. They (the index html and the template php) are in the same directory and call the same php files.

Answer (score 0):

It actually works if I iframe the said html page.

```
<iframe name="FRAME2" src="http://www.szerelmifajdalomklinika.hu/wp-content/themes/constructor/index2.html" frameborder="1" width="450" height="400"></iframe>
```

to the page template.